# Не работает счетчик в Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, counter

почему не работает счетчик в Node JS. Именно такой как в примере. Тема локальные переменные

```js
function makeCounter() { 
    var currentCount = 1; 
    return function() {
        return currentCount++;
    };
}

var counter = makeCounter();
console.log(counter());
```

Вывод всегда = 1.

При выполнение на стороне клиента счетчик работает!

Comment: Приведите примеры, как вы вызываете счётчик и проверяете его значение.

Comment: Привёл в вопросе

Comment: Но ведь при первом вызове он и должен возвращать 1. Если вызывать ещё и ещё (повторять последнюю строчку), возвращаемое число должно увеличиваться.

Comment: В том то и дело что нет, даже если вызывать не сколько раз

Comment: @vsemozhebuty Скриншот [ссылка](https://ibb.co/PmjkLxV)

Comment: У Вас там return currentCount; :)

Comment: @Sadykhzadeh спасибо заметил)

Comment: Да, пропущено ++.